# List all "true" variables

Tags: javascript

Here my problem with Javascript, I have this :

```
for (var rep = [], i = 4; i < 19; i++) {
  if (itemResponses[i].getScore() == 0)
    rep[i] = "Is not OK"
  else
    rep[i] = "Is OK"
}
```

itemResponses[i] = The questions of a form,
itemResponses[i].getScore() = The score (points) of the question

Then now, I want to set a value `channelMsg` that list all itemResponses where `rep[i] == "Is not OK"`

Like `channelMsg = Question #6 Is not Ok, Question #9 Is not Ok`

Any help would be welcome, i'm beginner.

Thx :)

Comment: What is `itemResponses` array in your code?

Comment: Welcome @Jhon Dipster, You can just remove the else and the inner lines

Comment: Use `array_filter()` to find all the array elements that match a condition.

Comment: itemResponses[i].getScore is responses from gform

Answer (score 1):

Comments added.

```js
// initialize your variables
var responses = [];

// for each iteration, check for error and push to the array
for(let i=4; i<19; i++){
  if(itemResponses[i] && !itemResponses[i].getScore()){
    responses.push(`itemResponses[${i}] is not OK`);
  }
}

// if array has length, join the responses by comma
let errorMessage = responses.length ? responses.join(',') : '';

// log / use the error message
console.log(errorMessage);
```

Comment: `[].join(',')` returns `""`, an empty string.

Comment: @ChloeAnderson Didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()`. Then use `.join()` to combine them with `,`.

```
channelMsg = rep.filter(el => el == 'Is not OK').join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks you <3 Its working fine, and how could I do the same but for `itemResponses[i].getScore = 0` ?
Tryied `itemResponses.getScore().filter(el => el == '0').join(',')` but ofc not working

Comment: `getScore()` doesn't return an array. Use `map()` to get an array of all the scores: `itemResponses.map(resp => resp.getScore()).filter(el => el == '0').join(',')`

Comment: itemResponses[4] = Question #4, 
itemResponses[4].getScore() = The score of Question #4

I'd like something like `channelMsg = Question #4, Question #7` You see ? To have all the response with 0 point

Thanks for ur help !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Sounds like you really want `zeroResponses = itemResponses.filter(r => r.getScore() == 0)`

Comment: You need to learn how these functions work so you can figure it out yourself, I'm not going to keep writing your code for you.

Comment: Hum, the itemResponses[i] is the number of the question of the form, the itemResponses[i].getScore() is getting the score of the question [i] , then what I'd like is a result in channelMsg is the list of the questions where the score is 0 like `Question #1 , Question #5, Question #9` you  see ?

Comment: You need to update the question to show what you're really trying to do. Add the sample data to the question.

Comment: You probably need to use `.map()`. The function receives the array index as the second argument, you can use that to index `channelMsg` to get the corresponding question.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I edited, I'll try to work on all the infos I got now to get it by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to implement that into the for loop you already have. Try creating `let channelMsg = ''` before the loop.

Then inside the loop,

```
if (itemResponses[i].getScore() == 0){
              rep[i] = "Is not OK"
              channelMsg += rep[i] + ', '
          }
         else {
              rep[i] = "Is OK"
         }
```

then after you finish the loop, just delete the last comma with something like

```
channelMsg[channelMsg.length-1] = ''
```

or not if you want to leave the trailing comma.

Welcome to the community, don't give up!

Edit: I just realized, all you're going to get is a string of

```
'Is not ok, Is not ok, ...'
```

You probably want to include the index, or something else, so try:

```
if (itemResponses[i].getScore() == 0) {
              rep[i] = "Is not OK"
              channelMsg += '#' + i + ' ' + rep[i] + ', '
          }
         else {
              rep[i] = "Is OK"
         }
```

Also, instead of that clunky expression, try a string [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like
`#${i} {rep[i]},`  or  `#${i} Is not ok,` since you that's what you are saving as.

Note: I can't figure out how to escape the character, but the template literal is surrounded by backticks, the key above your tab key, to the left of the '1'.

Comment: Are you a Python programmer? You're missing `{}` around the `if` block.

Comment: Hey nice thks , I'll try to understand and try this now , you understood what I've forgot :)

Comment: It seems to add me ony the last "Is not Ok" , result is `#18 Is not Ok`

Comment: I'll work on your part of your code to get it by myself, thanks you for you help :)

Comment: @Barmar I do both. In this instance, I just copied the code he had.  Which just made me realize that might be an error he's getting.